# Azure Kusto - how to parse a string looking for the last node?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I am writing kusto queries to analyze the state of the database when simple queries run for a long time.

**For ex:**  data and type = SQL in dependencies is a sql server query.  If its duration at timestamp 2019-06-24T16:41:24.856 is >= 15000 (>= 15 secs)
I would like to query and analyze  the dtu_consumption_percent out of AzureMetrics from 2019-06-24T16:40:24.856 to 2019-06-24T16:42:24.856.  ( 1 min before and 1 min after the query completion time) to determine the state of the database at that point in time.

**Question:** I wonder if anyone can give me pointers on getting the database name out of the target column from dependencies?

target looks as below:

`tcp:sqlserver-xxx-xxxxxx.database.windows.net | DDDDD`

and I am needing to extract `DDDDD` to join to AzureMetrics column Resource.

Thank you!

Comment: to clarify: is this the value you want to parse: `tcp:sqlserver-xxx-xxxxxx.database.windows.net | DDDDD`? and is `DDDDD` the substring you want to parse out of it?

Comment: That is correct.  The string that represents server | database can be varied in length so is DDDDD. Our server names and database names are varied in lengths. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yoni says you can use parse, or you could use substring:

```
let T = datatable(Value:string) [
'tcp:sqlserver-xxx-xxxxxx.database.windows.net | DDDDD',
'udp:appserver-yyy-yyyyyy.database.contoso.com | EEEEE'
];
T
// Look for the pipe and take everything after it as the value
| extend ToSubstring = substring(Value, indexof(Value, "|")+1)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/substringfunction

However if you find yourself doing this a lot you may want to take a look at Custom Fields:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/custom-fields

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `parse` operator:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parseoperator

```
print value = 'tcp:sqlserver-xxx-xxxxxx.database.windows.net | DDDDD'
| parse value with * "| " database
```

this returns:

```
| value                                                 | database |
|-------------------------------------------------------|----------|
| tcp:sqlserver-xxx-xxxxxx.database.windows.net | DDDDD | DDDDD    |
```